# How to copy needed JxBrowser files on External Thread on Application startup

Tags: jxbrowser

JxBrowser files are sometimes 150 MB so when JavaFX application starts up it lags till the are copied on the disc .

Can i somehow modify that functionality in order the `Copy,Extract` or whatever the JxBrowser library is doing to happen on external Thread and when it's ready i notify the user or show a progress bar ....

Yes it happens one time but it's important to not lag the application.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is possible to create a new Browser instance in another thread. In this case, GUI won't be blocked and during the process of extraction, you can show some kind of a spinner.

2) You can manually extract, for example, the library *jxbrowser-win32-6.21.jar* (depending on your OS). Then before the first JxBrowser run - call `System.setProperty("jxbrowser.chromium.dir", "<a_directory_with_the_files_here>")`

Comment: So let's say i just start the appication for the first time and it hasn't extracted all the needed dll and stuff from JXBrowser jar ..... Actually when it extracts them? When i create the first Browser instance ? I have also used `System.setProperty("jxbrowser.chromium.dir", "folderName")` so it creates a folder for example with name `folderName` but when that extraction happens ?

Comment: Please check this article for the details: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000015146-chromium-binaries

JxBrowser extracts the binaries from appropriate JAR file into user’s temp directory at the first run.

Comment: Thank you .... it extracts the binaries using which Thread ? It makes another Thread or uses main JavaFX or Java Thread that the application is running ? I am asking because this is very important for application first run .

Comment: It extracts the binaries in the same thread where the first Browser Instance is created.

Comment: That means JavaFX Thread .... well that's very bad because the application lags for 7 seconds at least . So i have to create the first Browser Instance on a separate Thread ?

Comment: yes, or you can extract Chromium binaries to a pre-defined location as suggested earlier.

Comment: My problem is the cost of extraction. You know i mean the application is lagging until the needed files are copied to the hard drive or ssd . It's an IO procedure, it shouldn't happen in main Thread.